# Mocking a pdo object gives simple parameter error

Tags: php, mysql, unit-testing, pdo, phpunit

I'm trying to mock a PDO object but am getting an error that reads "PDO::__construct() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given"

The class that I am mocking is here:

```
class MockPDO extends PDO
{

public function __construct() {
try 
    {
     $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=somedatabase";
     parent::__construct($dsn, "root", "root"); 
    }
    catch (PDOException $exception) 
    {
     die($exception->getMessage());
    }
 }
}
```

My test class is here

```
class DatabaseTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
public function testFindById() {
$pdo = $this->getMock('PDO', array('prepare'));
$stmt = $this->getMock('PDOStatement', array('execute', 'fetch'));
$stmt->expects($this->once())->method('execute')->with($this->equalTo(array(':id' => 2)));
$stmt->expects($this->once())->method('fetch');

$pdo->expects($this->once())->method('prepare')
  ->with($this->equalTo('SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE id => :id'))
  ->will($this->returnValue($stmt));
}
```

I know this is simple, but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO \_\_constructs expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904852/pdo-constructs-expects-at-least-1-parameter-0-given)

Comment: The solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19904852/pdo-constructs-expects-at-least-1-parameter-0-given cannot be applied here because I can only extend phpunit's test framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for this problem is to create a wrapper class for pdo. This is for destroying the constructor. 
Unless you provide valid connection string to the constructor

Example how to provide constructor arguments:

```
$pdo = $this->getMock('PDO', array('prepare', '__construct'), ["mysql:host=server;dbname=db;"]);
```

Solution:

```
class PDOMock extends \PDO {
    public function __construct() {} }

class PDOTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function setup() {
        $pdo = $this->getMockBuilder('PDOMock')
            ->getMock();
    } }
```

Answer (score 2):

PhpUnit calls the constructor of the object, unless you explicitly tell not to

```
$pdo = $this->getMockBuilder('PDO')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->setMethods(array('prepare'))
    ->getMock();
```